# How to create several root-like and non_root-like linux users

Tags: rhel, users, root, non-root-user, useradd

I have a red-hat system with its root and non-root users.
I have to create n new root-like users and m new non-root users.
Basically I have to clone the 2 kind of users already present on the server. 
The purpose is to give to each person able accessing to the server their unique credentials. Someone can act as root, someone else can act as a non-root user.

I considered it different than giving root power to another user, because I have to create new root-like users.

Comment: `sudo` is the usual mechanism for this. You can give certain users direct access to the privileges required with `pam_cap.so` but there's often administrative overhead involved with that.

Comment: `sudo`, but consider also capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the normal user accounts as usual (`useradd` perhaps, or some GUI tool if you like). For the users you want to give root access, you have two choices.

Either (a) use `sudo`, and add the accounts of the admin users to `/etc/sudoers`, or (b) create another set of user accounts for them, with a different name but UID = 0 and have them use `su` to access those accounts.

Creating separate UID 0 accounts has the advantage that the admins can have a separate root password, and those passwords can be distinct for the different admins.

Comment: Eh, don't go creating multiple users with UID zero (or users that share UID with _any_ other user). Using `sudo` is much much cleaner, much less error prone and easier to maintain. The "advantage" that you mention is still the same for `sudo` accounts.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it works just fine, thank you very much. And yeah, ok, sure you could do two accounts with UID > 0, one with sudo access, the other without. As far as I can tell that would be the only way to get sudo to ask for different admin passwords for different users (i.e. two users, four passwords). Though I do suspect it would get confusing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Log into the machine that needs the accounts. Become the user, `root`.

```
sudo -i
```

After becoming `root`, add users and set passwords. Create as many users as required.

```
adduser $username
passwd $username
```

For each user who should be able to become the `root` user, add the user to the right `sudo` group. It's `wheel` on RHEL.

```
usermod -aG wheel $username
```

Make sure your `sudo` configuration allows the group to become `root`.

```
visudo
```

You'll see two configurations for the `wheel` group, as follow.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Uncomment one of the configuration options and save the file. For example, to configure `sudo` to make each user type their password to become `root` or to execute command as `root`, use the following line.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now, you have created created m regular users and n privileged users who can become `root` or execute command as `root`.